# Xamarin Forms - Android ViewCellRenderer - SetSelectedITem background color to Transparent

Tags: android, xamarin.forms

I'm trying to set the background color of the selected row of a `ListView` transparent on Android.
Here is my custom renderer taken from [there](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/99499/how-to-change-background-color-of-a-cell-if-that-cell-is-selected-in-xamamrin-froms):

```
public class ExCellRenderer : ViewCellRenderer
    {
        protected override View GetCellCore(Cell item, View convertView, ViewGroup parent, Context context)
        {
            var cell = base.GetCellCore(item, convertView, parent, context);
            if (parent is ListView lv)
            {

                lv.SetSelector(global::Android.Resource.Color.Transparent));
                lv.CacheColorHint = global::Android.Graphics.Color.Transparent;
            }
            return cell;
        }
    }
```

My issue is that `lv.SetSelector` causes a crash:

> Android.Content.Res.Resources+NotFoundException: Resource ID #0xffffff

UPDATE

The code does work. The question is useless. I don't delete it because others have replied and I thank them.
The issue is VS needs 10 000 rebuilds before taking any Android change into account...

Comment: Codes works well  on my side, so I suggest you clean and rebuild, if it still not work, please delete the bin and obj folder and then restart your VS.

Comment: My mistake for not having deleted the question yesterday. The code is fine, I had just forgot that VS needs 10k rebuilds beurre taking a change into account.